# can you saute lentils with butter (masoor dal)

Tags: indian-cuisine, sauteing, lentils

After cooking masoor dal in pressure cooker, I used to saute it with ghee but since I don't have ghee and it's midnight, can I saute it with butter? will it taste bad?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it, just be careful not using too high a temperature so not to burn the butter.

Answer (score 0):

You could clarify the butter yourself. Melt your butter completely over a gentle heat, or on a low setting in a microwave. Skim any white froth from the top. Gently pour off the clear yellow butterfat from the milky residue underneath.

Comment: As a non-Indian who's eaten at Indian restaurants many 100s of times and cooked curries several dozen times, I wonder if the difference between butter and ghee  that critical?  If so why?  Would you immediately notice a taste difference?  Or texture?  Or does the ghee simply get hotter and thus make the other ingredients cook differently?

Comment: I would certainly notice a taste difference, in European cooking, too.. rich (mouth-feel?), sweet, aromatic.. I would love to know exactly why. Certainly whole butter will not fry spices for a _tarka_ .It would boil then burn before the oil remains. Maybe the aroma is something to do with the prominence of [lactones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactone)? Depending where you are, most Indian restaurants will use vegetable, not butter, _ghee_.